# In sharepoint (MOSS) how to add a web part to a parent site to display wiki content

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

I have a SharePoint 2007 wiki.  Within the wiki site document library I've successfully created a view where I use a [ME] filter to filter on an added column to show only documents where the added column = [ME].

Is it possible to display this wiki view using a shared web part on the parent side default page using the out of the box tools to add a shared web part?

The structure of the site is something like this.

SharePoint Parent Site
 -- Doc Lib
 -- List
 -- Wiki Site
 ------ Wiki Doc Lib with added column

I'm trying to add a web part on the default page of the parent site (the parent of the wiki site).

Option 1 - the Wiki Site and wiki document library aren't visible in the "Lists and Libraries" add web part dialogue to add.

Option 2 - I've tried a content query web part.  the content query web part does allow the selection of the child site and wiki library but i can't get it to show the page records.  It also doesn't display the added column in the filter list.

Comment: I believe this question should be asked in StackOverflow.

Comment: I think it's closer to administration coz no custom code is involved.

Comment: That's why it's here versus StackOverflow, looking for an admin method versus a programming method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 2 (CQWP) is the way to go, but it will take a little bit of customizing.

After you point the CQWP at your list, you need to change the "Library Type" to be "Wiki Page Library" or your data won't show up properly. It defaults to "Pages Library" which doesn't work for Wiki's.

As far as adding your custom field, you need to edit the CAML code for the web part and edit the field data. Here is a tutorial page with a section on how to do that (the section title is "Modify the CQWP to Include Additional Data"):
www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx

Also, here is the technical details from MSDN on customizing the CQWP:
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx